# How to call a function triggered by other event only when an authorized event is received?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a a Socket.io connection that implements jwt authorization. I already managed to emit the auth token and get a response, but I want to emit what is inside of "onClick()" only when the connection is authorized. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:8000',{transports: ['websocket']});

socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('Connected?');

  socket
    .on('authenticated', function () {
      console.log('Authenticated');
      socket.emit('message', 'hello');
    })
    .emit('authenticate', {token: jwt}) //send the jwt

});


onClick = () => {

    socket.emit('message','button clicked');
}
```

Comment: You're already checking if the user is Authenticated when they try connecting to the site, if they can connect, then they should be able to click the button.

Comment: So why don't you just set some state in the `authenticated` event and check it in the `onClick`?